# Linking libs into a binary in order to make it static on most of linux environment

Tags: gcc, build, static-libraries, binaryfiles, musl

I am currently searching for a way to make a binary that I just compiled, a portable binary for most of all linux environment. I was considering Ermine but it's not free (looking for a free solution right now) and tried also with Statifier but didn't work either. Here is the details on the binary I am trying to make static and portable:

```
sirius@blackb0x:~/MINING/ARIONUM/ariominer/build$ ldd /home/sirius/MINING/ARIONUM/ariominer/build/ariominer
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff692fe000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fdfee979000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007fdfee775000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007fdfee45f000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007fdfee159000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007fdfedf42000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fdfedb79000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fdfeeb97000)
```

If some could tell me how exactly to link all the libs to the binary so it could run easy on all or almost all linux env (2.6.18 kernels to latest) it would be very appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: As provided in another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34548856/gcc-linking-libc-static) try to statically link libc and other libraries, like 'code gcc -nostdlib -static ./libc.a'

Answer (score 1):

Rebuild the program and its dependencies from source (while having `LIBS` set to `-static`), and make sure to pass `--enable-static --disable-shared` to their `configure` scripts.

If that doesn't work, just compile it on a very old machine and provide binaries for glibc and musl.

Comment: I don't usually make static libraries but I will bookmark this to get back to when I build one, thanks.