# How to build a Shared Library but use static glibc on Linux?

Tags: c, linux, gcc

I'm trying to create a shared library on centos using gcc 4.8.2

shared library code:

```
//reload.c
int func(int num){
    return num++;
}
```

link command:

```
gcc -fPIC -shared reload.c -o reload.so
```

use ldd command:

```
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffe6aa93000)
libc.so.6 => /usr/lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007f27feb97000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f27ff169000)
```

Now, Want to statically link glibc, how to write it?

like it:

```
ldd xxx.so
    not a dynamic executable
```

I tried the build options, but the error.

```
gcc -fPIC -shared reload.c -o reload.so -Wl,-Bstatic -lc
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc_s
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc_s
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

thank you very much

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26277283/gcc-linking-libc-static-and-some-other-library-dynamically-revisited

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not have dependencies to glibc at all for your code above, so the easiest way is to compile with the flag `-nostdlib`:

```
$ gcc -fPIC -shared reload.c -o reload.so -nostdlib
$ ldd reload.so
statically linked
```